# Giving a Pearl of Speech to a creature with Int too low for language?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, ability-scores, languages

What happens if you give a pearl of speech to a creature with low intelligence? Say you give a pearl of speech to an owlbear with an intelligence of 2.

The pearl states that:

> While absorbed, the pearl grants you the ability to speak and understand a specific language, such as Dwarven or Draconic. Each pearl is created for a specific language, and you can have only one pearl of speech active at a time.

So is the owlbear magically now able to speak and understand languages even though its intelligence score is only a 2? Or does the intelligence score override the magic ability of the item?

Answer (score 19):

Typically, without using trickery, magic, or violence, a creature can't *make* another creature absorb a ***pearl of speech*** (*Magic Item Compendium* 118) (600 gp; 0 lbs.) as its description says

> When **you** place a *pearl of speech* upon **your** tongue (a standard action), it is absorbed into your mouth until you speak the proper command word to release it.

(Emphasis mine.) So an owlbear (*Monster Manual* 206) must itself—for whatever reason—place the *pearl of speech* upon its *own* tongue for the *pearl* to be absorbed. This isn't an impossible thing to convince an owlbear to do, but doing so usually entails some risk. For instance, a low-level ranger probably must be fairly optimized for the [wild empathy](http://dndsrd.net/ranger.html#ranger-wild-empathy) special ability to get an owlbear to do this.

That said, once the owlbear *does* absorb the *pearl*, the owlbear can then communicate in the language the *pearl* provides… to the best of its ability, anyway. That is, this reader suspects that the owlbear's physiology sadly still limits it to mostly hooting and growling. See, while the pearl "grants [the creature] the ability to speak and understand a specific language," it doesn't also *change* the creature's underlying (albeit admittedly magical) biology. The *pearl*'s description says that *pearls* were "created by drow and used to command their slaves without stooping to learn their foul languages," not that they were, for instance, created by druids to give animals the gift of speech!

Thus this reader believes that, as written, an absorbed *pearl* essentially grants the creature 1 rank in skill [Speak Language](http://dndsrd.net/skillsAll.html#speak-language) as if it had picked Common, Elven, Slaad, Clockwork Horror, or whatever language the *pearl* contains, but that virtual skill rank doesn't, in turn, permit an owlbear—like a disturbing combination of [Yogi Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Bear) and [Woodsy Owl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodsy_Owl)—to actually and for-reals *talk.*

However, this player and this DM knows that's no fun. Like, *at all.*

Thus, in this DM's campaigns, when a normally noncommunicative creature absorbs a *pearl of speech*, that creature gains the full capacity to communicate in the language the *pearl* provides out loud and for-reals using actual speech, just as if every listener were affected by the 1st-level druid spell [*speak with animals*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#speak-with-animals) (*Player's Handbook* 281). Further, like that spell, the *pearl*'s presence "doesn't make [a creature] any more friendly or cooperative than normal[, and] wary and cunning [creatures] are likely to be terse and evasive, while the more stupid ones make inane comments." So, in this DM's campaigns, that owlbear will be making *a lot* of inane comments. All the time. And this DM says, sincerely, *thank you* for paying 600 gp to give me *that* role-playing opportunity.

Similarly, this player would try to convince a DM who was reluctant to rule likewise that the *pearl* should work this way in that DM's campaigns, too, if for no other reason than because the *pearl* is a lot of fun for the DM.

---

***Note:*** In this DM's campaigns, pearls of speech *are frequently used by druids, paladins, wizards and others so that their animal companions, familiars, and special mounts can talk. My campaigns have only improved as a result.*

Answer (score 5):

By RAW, I believe it would. Specific trumps general, and the general effect of not being able to speak due to a low int is trumped by the specific rule that the pearl allows this specific language.

By RAI, I don't really know. The intention (or existence thereof) of the designers for animals and the pearl interacting is not clear.

In the end, it probably boils down to GM fiat. I'd be inclined to allow it, depending of course on player intention and its ramifications, since it can enable fun and probably not too disrupting options.

Answer (score -2):

Well, just on pure logic: the owlbear should be able to understand the language itself. It might just not understand the meaning once things go beyond its primal thoughts. I can talk to you -in perfect english- about advanced quantum stuff, but that doesnt mean you are really understanding what i say.

Comment: Could you back this up with any citation of game text? Pure logic requires establishing your base assumptions are true, which here would be done through citing game text or rules.

Comment: Yeah, i dont really have a authority-source. The anwser is more based on real life (there are a lot of animals that can understand some degree of language), and the fact i couldnt find anything for a while that suggested otherwise

Comment: If there's indication that in-game language works just like learning real-life language that way, then that would be worth citing as an indication it would indeed work that way.